# Transition in the application with navigation hooks

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have an application that uses Hooks

My navigation:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={Home} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    <Stack.Screen name='Learning' component={Learning}
      options={({ route }) => ({
        headerTransparent: true,
        title: route.params.screen
      })} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

The standard transition is the outgoing screen from the bottom of the screen

I would like to make the screen disappear and a second one appear (fadeIn, fadeOut)

In class-based applications, I can use this library to change the style of transition between screens:
(it doesn't work on hooks)

[react-navigation-transitions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation-transitions)

Comment: Have you tried passing a `screenOptions` prop to your `Stack.Navigator` and setting `transitionConfig: fadeIn` in it?

Comment: @giotskhada yes but not work

Comment: Have you tried using `TransitionPresets` instead? You can import that from `@react-navigation/stack` and put this in your options `...TransitionPresets.RevealFromBottomAndroid`. More on that here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#pre-made-configs.